# jQuery Validate - how to use the errorMap or errorList

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

This may seem like such a novice question but here it goes. Inside my `invalidHandler` for the jQuery Validate plugin I have the following.

```
invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
    $firstitem = (validator.errorList[0].element);
    alert($firstitem);
}
```

All I want to do is get the name of the first item in the `errorMap` or `errorList`. Here are some things I have tried:

`alert($firstitem.attr('name'));` also `alert($firstitem.html());`. Not sure how to access the name from here. I could just query the DOM, but the error elements may not have been updated so `$("#form .error");` may not pick up the updated error set if any exists.

Any ideas ?

Comment: It might be easier to help you if you explain what you want to do with the `errorList`/`errorMap`; it seems to me you're going about it the wrong way.

Comment: Did you follow the [the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate)?  You could also look at [other SO answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery-validate%5D+errormap).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$firstitem` is just a node here, not a jQuery object, so it should have its name as a property, `$firstitem.name`.

At the very least, you can `console.log($firstitem)` to see what it looks like.

Comment: Good lord...how could I have been so dumb ... Thanks Mathletics, it worked.